# How to calculate a vector of midpoints or medians from a vector of cut points?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of cut points, for the purposes of this question, generated as follows:

```
> seq(0,50,10)
[1]  0 10 20 30 40 50
```

This is a numeric vector of length 6. I would like to generate a numeric vector of midpoints, to get either of the following (both of which meet my requirements), of length one less of the cuts (in this case, 5).

```
# midpoints, exactly
5 15 25 35 45
# medians excluding right
4.5 14.5 24.5 34.5 44.5
```

Not finding a pre-rolled function, I developed a procedure that takes a numeric vector as an argument (the cut points) and returns a vector (the midpoints). It works by taking the median of index 1 and index 2 and appending it to a vector, then the median of index 2 and index 3, and so on until the last index is NULL.

Surely, I can't be the first one to have this need. Is there a package with such a procedure? I don't mind rolling by own, but honestly I'd rather use a package that's been subject to the rigors of public scrutiny.

Thanks

Comment: Add diff(vec) to head(vec, -1)

Comment: @BondedDust - `diff(vec)/2` surely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Split the difference?

```
a <- seq(0,50,10)
a[-length(a)] + diff(a)/2
```

Comment: Yes, Neal, and thanks. I hesitate to make my solution public, my brain has been pickeled by Perl, but here is my attempt. Gives the same result as yours, but yours obviously much better. +1.
    t <- function(nv)
    {
        old.len <- length(nv)
        new.len <- old.len - 1
        vec <- numeric(new.len)
        i <- 1
        while(i < old.len)
        {
            midpoint <- (nv[i] + nv[i+1]) / 2
            vec[i] <- midpoint
            i <- i + 1
        }
        return(vec)
    }

Answer (score 5):

Another attempt using `filter`, which would allow you to weight a mid-point right in the middle, or some degree to the left or right:

```
x <- seq(0,50,10)

head(filter(x, c(0.5,0.5)), -1)
#[1]  5 15 25 35 45

head(filter(x, c(0.75,0.25)), -1)
#[1]  7.5 17.5 27.5 37.5 47.5

head(filter(x, c(0.25,0.75)), -1)
#[1]  2.5 12.5 22.5 32.5 42.5
```

Comment: Also can be used on `x` defined inline (doesn't require `x` to be stored), e.g., `head(filter(1:10, c(.5, .5)), -1)`